# Call execv in OpenMP loop

Tags: c, bash, exec, openmp

I would like to run an executable in an OpenMP loop.
I tried to do it with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <omp.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        char thread_name[4];
        sprintf(thread_name, "%d", thread_id);

        printf("%s\n", thread_name);

        char* arg[] = {"task", thread_name, NULL};
        execv("./task", arg); 

    }
}
```

The corresponding executable can be generated with gcc like this:

```
gcc -fopenmp hello.c -o hello
```

The task script is a very simple bash script:

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "Hello, I am process $1"
echo 'Please for me for 10 seconds...'
sleep 10
echo 'Thank you!'
```

And I run my program like this:

```
./hello
```

from a directory containing both "hello" executable and "task" script.

> 3
>
> 2
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> Hello, I am process 3
>
> Please for me for 10 seconds...
>
> Thank you!

It seems that when execv function is called by the first thread (the 3rd one in my example), other calls to execv are skipped.

Does someone know what the problem is here?

Thanks!

EDIT: new code with system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <omp.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        char thread_name[4];
        sprintf(thread_name, "%d", thread_id);

        char command[50];

        strcat(command, "./task ");
        strcat(command, thread_name);

        system(command);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `execv` will replace the current process with a new one created with the parameters given to the function.

To achieve what you want, you should use `system`, or maybe the couple `fork`/`execv`.

Comment: And to be clear, "replac[ing] the current process" involves destroying all its threads other than the one calling `execv()` (or any other `execve()` wrapper function).  I'm inclined to prefer the recommendation to use `system()` in this case, for although it takes a bit more setup on the front end, it looks like it would be simpler overall for the use presented in the question.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. I think it should work but there is another problem: it seems that the script "task" is only executed by the two first threads. For the last two ones, I get the following error: no such file or directory. Do you know why?

Comment: @Aleph: The `strace` command will be your friend. run `strace -f -ff -o hellotrace hello`. It will generate a trace file for each of your threads and processes. Then read the resulting trace files.

Comment: Thank you Klaas! Strace seems to be very useful but for the moment I am not able to understand the outputs. Maybe I need to read the documentation first.